# Wine installation issues

Tags: 18.04, wine

i've been trying to install wine on 18.04 for 7 hours, and i've gotten absolutely no results

every tutorial i find doesn't work

the only thing resembling a hint as to what was wrong i could find was this:

```
root@valeri-same-pc:~# apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]                   
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                            
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                            
Hit:4 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Ign:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... bionic InRelease               
Ign:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/artful bionic InRelease  
Err:13 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... bionic Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.4.69 443]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Err:15 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/artful bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.4.69 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/artful bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Why not run `sudo apt install wine`?

Comment: Line 15 contains 'artful' (17.10's name) where it shouldn't, making the bionic that follows it completely out of place.  That line is wrong., and possibly you've made the same error on line 13 (*I have no idea what the is supposed to be; unless you keyed that into your sources file for some reason*)

Comment: sudo doesn't work
and i dont know why the artful thing is happening

Comment: Hmm if `sudo` doesn't work, and you are supposed to have access to it (you always need `sudo` to install software globally) someone has broken your  system and you should investigate that bigger problem (or reinstall)

Answer (score 0):

The line should read:
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main

That's in /etc/apt/sources.list unless you made a separate file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

SO after you get the sudo issue resolved, remove the "artful" reference.